# Showing selected option in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem displaying the default selection "Choose School" in my second select.What should i add in my JavaScript just to show this selection?

For example right after loading the page.The default selected item  for first dropdown is showing "Choose Location" which is fine. But in my second select, Choose School is not showing, Why? What is something wrong with the JavaScript?What am i missing here? 
Any new learning is much appreciated.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $cat = $('select[name=category]'),
    $items = $('select[name=items]');

    $cat.change(function(){
      var $this = $(this).find(':selected'),
      rel = $this.attr('rel'),
      $set = $items.find('option.' + rel);

      if ($set.size() < 0) {
        $items.hide();
        return;
      }
      $items.show().find('option').hide();

      $set.show().first().prop('selected', true);
    });
  });
```

```css
 .cascade {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category">
    <option value="0">Choose location</option>
    <option  value="1" rel="1">Bacolod</option>
    <option  value="2" rel="2">Bohol</option>
    <option  value="3" rel="3">Cebu</option>
    <option  value="4" rel="4">Manila</option>
   
</select>
    <br>
  <select name="items" class="cascade">
    <option>Choose school</option>
    <option  value="1" class="1">Bacolod Tay Tung High School</option>
    <option  value="2" class="3">University of Southern Philippines Foundation</option>
    <option  value="3" class="2">Dr. Cecilio Putong National High School</option>
    <option  value="4" class="1">Jack and Jill School</option>
    <option  value="5" class="4">British School Manila</option>
    <option  value="6" class="2">Holy Spirit School of Tagbilaran</option>
    <option  value="7" class="4">Chinese International School Manila</option>
    <option  value="8" class="2">Ubay National Science High School</option>
    <option  value="9" class="3">Abellana National School</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class inside "chose school" option as `class="0"` and find extra parameter as `option.0`.

```
$set = $items.find('option.0, option.' + rel);
<option class="0">Choose school</option>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Now i get it why i cant able to display it.

Comment: Because you finding only the options, who have class as "1, 2 ,3 or 4" in the "item" select tag. "$set = $items.find('option.' + rel);" and "Choose school" option doesn't have any classes as "1, 2 ,3 or 4", so we added "0" as className and changed the finding code as "$set = $items.find('option.0, option.' + rel);"